# Как подружить docker-compose и docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

У меня есть docker-compose.yml файл который описывает, как поднять django, celery и postgres.

Как мне упаковать все это в один образ для дистрибуции, чтобы заходя на сервер я забирал единый образ с docker hub'а и разворачивал все одной командой?

Как я понял, docker hub это об одном image собранном на основе Dockerfile, а не docker-compose.

Мне кажется, я не правильно мыслю. Пожалуйста, направьте меня в нужное русло.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Как я понял, docker hub это об одном image собранном на основе Dockerfile, а не docker-compose.

Все верно. Единицей хранения докерхаба является образ контейнера.

> Как мне упаковать все это в один образ для дистрибуции, чтобы заходя на сервер я забирал единый образ с docker hub'а и разворачивал все одной командой?

"Одной командой" так сделать не получится. Варианты решения:

1. пересобрать мультиконтейнерное приложение, объединив все его части в одном образе. Пример такого приложения: https://hub.docker.com/r/analogic/poste.io/

   - плюсы:

     - "все в одном"
   - минусы:

     - не всегда возможно сделать
     - придется делать аналог init-системы: для apline подходит [OpenRC](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openrc&branch=edge), для Debian - [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini)
     - не удобно управлять, менять конфиги, так как "все в одном"
2. поднимать через docker-compose, но образы не будут собираться (это занимает время), а сразу браться с докерхаба

Расскажу о втором способе. Допустим, у нас есть такой `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  exim:
    build: ./exim
  spamassassin:
    build: ./spamassassin
  mongo:
    build: ./mongo
```

При старте сначала будут собираться три образа, и затем уже поднимется все приложение. Чтобы исключить этап сборки, можно использовать готовые образы:

```
version: '3'
services:
  exim:
    image: your_hub_login/exim:latest
  spamassassin:
    image: your_hub_login/spamassassin:latest
  mongo:
    image: your_hub_login/mongo:latest
```

Конечно, предварительно нужно залить образы на докерхаб.